# iOS app to show geolocation on map image?

Tags: ios, geo-location, mapping

I want an app where I can upload a picture of a map, in SVG or raster format, along with a little bit of config  data (perhaps the Geolocation of the bottom left hand corner, the scale, and any magnetic north corrections) and have it continuously display my location on that map.

The most recent need I’ve had for this was setting markers for an orienteering course.

Obviously I expect a commercial  application could  have better usability, with pinch pan and zoom and an easy way to calibrate the current location and scale. But anything would do to start with.

Can anyone suggest a suitable app?